# $A^2+A^{-1}+I_{2n+1}=O_{2n+1}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-calculus

Show that there not exists $A\in Gl_{2n+1}(\mathbb{C})$ s.t. $$A^2+A^{-1}+I_{2n+1}=O_{2n+1}.$$

My first attempt was to use the minimal polynomial. It should divide $x^3+x+1$.

Comment: The statement is false as written. Let $r$ be a root of $x^3+x+1$ and take $A=rI$.

Comment: Is $O_{2n+1}$ the zero matrix?

Comment: Take the companion matrix of$ x^3+x+1$.